# Таблица на JS, как подсветить столбец?

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть табличка, нужно при наведении курсора, чтобы подсвечивало столбец и строку. Со строкой получилось, помогите, пожалуйста, подсветить и столбец.

```
function maketable(){
let string = "<table>";

  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    string += "<tr>";

          for (let j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
              let res = i * j;
                  string += "<td>" + res + " </td>" ;
              }
  string += "</tr>";
  } 
  string  +="</table>";
  document.write(string);
}
maketable();
let tab = document.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');
console.log(tab);
this.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }
})
this.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
        if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
  }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Использование JS, как показывает этот пример, необязательно. Взято с оригинального ресурса [отсюда](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/):

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td, th {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

body:not(.nohover) tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td:hover::after,
thead th:not(:empty):hover::after,
td:focus::after,
thead th:not(:empty):focus::after { 
  content: '';  
  height: 10000px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;  
  top: -5000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td:focus::after,
th:focus::after {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* Focus stuff for mobile */
td:focus::before,
tbody th:focus::before {
  background-color: lightblue;
  content: '';  
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  position: absolute;  
  width: 10000px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="col">50kg</th>
        <th class="col">55kg</th>
        <th class="col">60kg</th>
        <th class="col">65kg</th>
        <th class="col">70kg</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="row">160cm</th>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>27</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="row">165cm</th>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="row">170cm</th>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="row">175cm</th>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: к сожалению, мне такой вариант не подходит. Мне нужно всё делать только на JS

Answer (score 1):

Рефакторинг.
Просто нужно ассоциировать все столбы с css стилем и/или классом.

```
let myClasses = document.getElementsByTagName('TD');
Array.prototype.foreach.call(myClasses, function(myClasses) {
  myClasses.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.target.style.backgorund = "black";
  })
  myClasses.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    event.target.style.backgorund = '';
  })
})
```

или же если присвоить класс;

```
let myClasses = document.getElementsByTagName('TD');
Array.prototype.foreach.call(myClasses, function(myClasses) {
  myClasses.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.target.className = "black";
  })
  myClasses.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    event.target.className = 'white';
  })
})
```